# How do I substitute literal [ followed by whitespace, then comma with just [

Tags: search-replace

I'm writing a vimscript function to edit some ruby code.  The line to be edited looks like this

```
foo = [ , "something" ]
```

And I want to remove the extraneous leading comma, so the line looks like this

```
 foo = [ "something" ]
```

vimscript:

```
let new_line = substitute(new_line, '\[\s*,', '[')
```

and it doesn't work

When I try the search by hand within vim, it will find the pattern `/s/\[\s*`, and move to it, but if I try to use substitution, `:s/\[\s*,/\[` it fails with `E486: Pattern not found: \[\s*,`

(Also fails if the preceding backslash left off the replacement string).  I use this type of substitution to successfully replace duplicate commas   `,  ,` and extraneous commas at the end    `, ]`.  What is different about this pattern that makes it fail in this way?

Comment: Did you really execute `:s/\[\s*,/\[/` without a range? The default range for the `substitute` command is the current line, so for your command to work the cursor should be on an appropriate line.

Comment: Yes, a previous line of vimscript moved it to the right line.  I extracted this line from the larger script to cut it down to the essence of my question.

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
let new_line = substitute(new_line, '\[\s*,', '[',)
```

throws an error, yes, but *a different one*:

```
E119: Not enough arguments for function: substitute
```

Second, once the missing argument is added:

```
let new_line = substitute(new_line, '\[\s*,', '[', '')
```

it does exactly what you want with the provided sample.

Comment: I apologize, I actually had a typo in the original post.  I had been playing with adding or leaving off the third argument.  On my system, this is not working.  Also, I realize my post is wrong in a second way.  I get NO error from vimscript, but when I do it in the browser, the error occurs.  I'm wondering if magic settings affect this?  or version?  I'm running:   VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 19 2020 21:23:05)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-2164

Comment: @Leonard what do you mean in the browser?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  Oh, lord, I do deserve to be down-voted for this one.  I apologize again.   I said in the browser, but I meant just in vim, using a last line mode command:    :s/\[\s*,/[

Comment: @Leonard don't worry. If you think your question is bad, you can still edit or delete it.

Comment: @Leonard your Ex command is different. Why not `:substitute/\[\s*,/[`?

Comment: @Leonard Regardless whether `magic` is set or not, a `\[` or `[` not accompanied by a matching `]` will search for a literal `[` (see `:help /[]`). But if `magic` is not set you must use `\*` instead of `*` (see`:help /star`),